# How I can use the GroupTemplate in my ListView Webcontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, datatable

I need help by a ASP.NET ListView and I have read many tutorials but I haven't found the answer to my Problem. I try to explain my Problem.

**To My Application:**

I use a DataTable with Data from our Active Directory and I fill my ListView with this DataTable about

```
 this.myListView.DataSource = //myDataTable
 this.myListView.DataBind();
```

For Example my DataTable have three Columns and a few Rows with Userinformations from ActiveDirectory.

[image]

If I start my ListView I get this...how in my Picture and my ASPX Code is...

```
<ListView ...>
 <LayoutTemplate>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <th> --> Firstname Header
     <th> --> Lastname Header
     <th> --> Location Header
    <tr>
    <tr> --->itemPlaceHolder
   </table>
 </LayoutTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
   <td> --> Firstname
   <td> --> Lastname
   <td> --> Location
  </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

My Idea:

I want if I show my ListView I get this...

[image]

For this  must use the GroupTemplate but I don't know how I can built my ListView that I can create this Groups. The Problem is that I must know which user have the location and than I must build the ListView.

Can anyone help me :(

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? It's exactly what I'm after too.